# Nodejs as javascript src?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was wondering if I can call nodejs as script src="nodeapp.js" and render for example an image or a piece of another javascript retrieved by node app?

Comment: You might be interested in http://browserify.org/

Comment: Please use google for simple things like this; `node.js in browser`

Answer (score 1):

No.  You cannot do that directly.

A script tag loads a script to be run in the browser in the browser environment.

Node apps run on the server in the server-side node environment.

---

You can create a server-side app (powered by node if you want) that will respond to a client-side request and produce the image you want to show.  But, the server-side code will run on the server-side, not in the browser.  Thus you make a request of the server and it does the work server-side and then delivers the result to the client.  It does not download the server-side code to the client and run it in the browser.